# What is Update function in MS SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi all last night i discussion with one of my senior he asked me one question . And that is really surprised me and really i don't ever hear about that . What is UPDATE Function in Sql server .

NOT a Update statement we are using .

Is really any function in sql server

```
UPDATE ()
```

Comment: How complex MS help system is evolved over time... Once upon a time it was enough to press F1 to see relevant help. After that it was much more convenient to search google - you got better answers and you wasted less time than in MS help. Now it seems best to enter your queries as stackoverflow questions :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[UPDATE() (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx)

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether an INSERT or UPDATE
>   attempt was made on a specified column of a table or view. UPDATE() is
>   used anywhere inside the body of a Transact-SQL INSERT or UPDATE
>   trigger to test whether the trigger should execute certain actions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. can you say me which type and where i can use this

Comment: @A.Goutam You use it in triggers and there is an example in the page I linked to.